# Extracting pull request creator in Github workflow from event

Tags: github-actions, slack, slack-api

I've written a Github workflow that runs when a PR is raised for a particular branch. It will check if Jira ticket is present and if not send a message to a slack channel. The action used for sending message to channel is,

```
      - name: Notify members
        env:
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_CHANNEL }}
        uses: Ilshidur/action-slack@2.0.2
        with:
          args: "No Jira ticket found in {{ EVENT_PAYLOAD.pull_request.html_url }} \n <@${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}> Please update the ticket number in PR"
        if: failure()
```

From docs I know in order to tag a user the format is <@User1>. I'm trying to get the `User1` from [github event payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-example-32) but it doesn't tag the person who raised the PR

Instead I get

```
No Jira ticket found in https://github.com/org/repo/pull/4
@JohnSmith Please update the ticket number in PR
```

I've tried with different payload options `github.event.pull_request.user.login`, `github.event.pull_request.user.id`, `github.event.sender.login`. None are tagging the user. Does the payload not have correct info or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with the Ilshidur/action-slack GH action, but I suspect what's tripping you up is that the slack username is question is different from the GitHub username, which is what you're getting from the github event payload.

Even if it isn't, the preferred format for the Slack API is to reference the User ID, not the username, as the former is immutable. So instead of `<@colmdoyle>`, you'd send `<@U9UFK54EA>`, but I don't know of any way you could store the GH username to Slack User ID without persisting it to a DB somewhere.